# C++ Custom Event missing parameters in VB6

Tags: c++, vb6

We have an old ActiveX control written in C++ 6.0.
It works ok in VB6.

Now I want to add a custom event called OnNewPosition.
I used the class wizard to set up this event.

This is the result:

```
EVENT_CUSTOM("OnNewPosition", FireOnNewPosition, VTS_R8 VTS_R8 VTS_R8)

void FireOnNewPosition(double x, double y, double z)
    {FireEvent(eventidOnNewPosition,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_R8  VTS_R8  VTS_R8), x, y, z);}
```

I can also fire this event

```
FireOnNewPosition(1 , 2 , 3);
```

In VB6, I can see the event:

```
Private Sub G_OnNewPosition()
```

But the parameters are missing.
It should look

```
Private Sub G_OnNewPosition(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double, ByVal z As Double)
```

I already tried to find out what the difference to other similar events is on the C++ side.
Can't find a difference:

```
EVENT_CUSTOM("OnSelect", FireOnSelect, VTS_I4)

void FireOnSelect(long id)
    {FireEvent(eventidOnSelect,EVENT_PARAM(VTS_I4), id);}
```

This one shows the parameters in VB6:

```
Private Sub G_OnSelect(ByVal id As Long)
```

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no direct solution found.

It *seems* it has to do with the name **OnNewPosition**.

I tried with another event name: **NewPosition**. With this one the parameters show up.

Then again I tried with **OnNewPosition** while **NewPosition** existed.
Result is the same, no parameters...

Tried to delete both, then again I gave **OnNewPosition** a try.
No luck.

Now I stick with **NewPosition** because it works.